# How to restore svn repository from zipped file with pristine in windows

Tags: svn, restore

I have a **svn** repository in **zip** format, it contains a folder in its original name, there is a sub folder of "**.svn**" in it, inside the "**.svn**", there is a sub folder named "**pristine**", in the "**pristine**" folder, there are a few sub folders (I guess they are for different versions), under each sub folder, there is a *.svn-base* file.

Can someone enlighten me with the procedure or tool to restore the repo please? Thank you so much in advance.

UPDATE:

Here is the steps I took following the suggestion:

1. create a new repo at: I:\Temp

[image]

[image]

2. checkout the repo to: I:\Tempwc

[image]
[image]
[image]

3. Unzip the "backup" to override the .svn folder under I:\Tempwc

[image]

4. Try to Commit from the merged .svn, seeing nothing:

[image]

Looks like there is nothing I can recover but the zip file does have a big volume of >1GB after unzipped.

What can I do now?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restore a repository from this. What you have is a Working Copy, which does not contain the full repository history. Your Working Copy only contains your local, uncommitted changes and enough cached data for you to look at recent logs and perform a diff between what was last pulled from the repository and your local changes.

To restore a repository, you need a repository dump file created by `svnadmin dump` or `svnrdump`

**Edit based on what you're doing**

You need to do the following:

1. Unpack the ZIP file to `I:\MyOldWC`
2. Delete `I:\MyOldWC\.svn`. It's useless now as there's no corresponding repository.
3. `svnadmin create I:\MyNewRepo`
4. `svn import i:\MyOldWC file:///i:/MyNewRepo`
5. `svn checkout file:///i:/MyNewRepo I:\MyNewWC`
6. Delete `I:\MyOldWC`

There is no history contained in your working copy backup (the zipfile) that can be imported into the repository. Your repository history is lost. This is a fact.

There's [a whole section of Chapter 5 of the Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.backup) explaining how to back up your repository. I suggest you implement some sort of backup process for your new repository before this happens again.

Comment: Thanks. then is it possible to recover just anything from this?

Comment: Nothing you can turn into a repository with history. You could commit everything except the `.svn` directory to a new repository, but you won't have any history. Any changes that were in the repository but you hadn't pulled down yet are gone. And if the repository contained more than what's in your working copy, that's lost.

Comment: is it possible to recover anything from it in offline mode? offline means not connecting to the working environment, thanks.

Comment: You have nothing _to_ recover. All you have is the working copy. What you see in the zipfile is all you've got. History, the rest of the repository structure, it's all gone. All you can do is start a new repository with the files you've got there and no history.

Comment: Thank you, can you share with some steps (with the commands)?

Comment: All you can do is `svnadmin create` a new repository on your server, check out an empty working copy from it, then copy your content into it, run `svn add` and then `svn commit`. But don't do any of that until you have backups established for your repository, else you'll find yourself losing your history and going through this again in the future.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my OP with step by step screenshots, can you please take a look and indicate what is wrong? I can't believe there is nothing to recover from the zip

Comment: Thank you but how to explain the zip file unzipps to 1GB content?

Comment: I don't have your zipfile so it's impossible for me to speculate on that.